# SQL Query Replace Text column as Hyperlink <a href="">

Tags: mysql, sql, text, replace, href

I have a table Products

```
ID | Productname |      Product_url                     |
+----+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | ShirtXS   | txthttps://www.product.com/shirt-xs  |
|  2 | TrousersM | txthttps://www.trousers.org/tM-sizeM |
```

Product_url is VARCHAR(512)
How to write SQL query to format Product_url column text value to `<a href="producttextvalue">Link</a>` ?

Basically, all values from Product_url field should become links with same link labels.

```
https://www.product.com/shirt-xs to <a href="https://www.product.com/shirt-xs">Link</a>  
https://www.trousers.org/tM-sizeM to <a href="https://www.trousers.org/tM-sizeM">Link</a>  

ID   | Productname |  Poduct_url  |
+----+-------------+--------------+
|  1 | ShirtXS     |     Link     |
|  2 | TrousersM   |     Link     |
```

Comment: Is this `txt` exists before each link in product_url column? And one suggestion - format the HTML code within your page, but not in database, i.e. keep in database the exact link only. Tmr if you need to show something different than `Link` you have to update again the whole table

Comment: this "txt" prefix doesnt exits in columns, i've added txt to prevent stackoverflow autoformat links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can use `CONCAT()` to add needed prefix and suffix around the URL, like:

```
UPDATE
    `products`
SET
    `product_url` = CONCAT('<a href="', product_url, '">Link</a>');
```

However, as I mentioned in my comment, better to keep the exact link only in your database and to format the HTML code within your front-end page.